# Out of memory error MATLAB:lang:StackOverflow

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, infinite-recursion

I'm developing a Matlab application that works fine uncompiled, but when I compiled it and tried running the executable, got this error :

> Out of memory. The likely cause is an infinite recursion within the
> program. Error in set (line 15) MATLAB:lang:StackOverflow

... which is unhelpful in that it doesn't say which function falls into an infinite recursion.  Is there a way to find whee the recursion is happening?

Comment: Code should not be running differently when compiled. Are you using the same inputs to the code? I think the only way of debugging a compiled MATLAB program is to add print statements, unfortunately.

Comment: There is no debugging in the compiled executable, which is why you have this frustrating error messages. Somewhere a variable seems to exceed its limits (stackoverflow -- kind of ironic^^). Either add print statements or comment prat of the function out to narrow down the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cris Luengo and max for the comments.
My application uses parts of the GUI Layout Toolbox, but the compiler does not look into toolbox folders to find dependencies (don't know why), so I had to add the folder manually.   Turns out that the GUI toolbox has a folder with the same name as a folder in my application  - that is what caused the recursion.  After renaming things to avoid this duplication and recompiling, the error disappeared and the packaged application runs fine.